# ArgumentException OptionsManager can't be converted to service type IOptions

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I'm trying to test if all services in my `IServiceCollection` can be resolved with following code:

```
static void TestServiceResolve(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    foreach (var item in services)
    {
        var serviceToResolve = item.ServiceType;
        var implemantationService = provider.GetService(serviceToResolve);
    }
}
```

It throws an exception:

> System.ArgumentException: Implementation type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1[TOptions]' can't be converted to service type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[TOptions]'

I already added `services.AddOptions();` and all the possible packages I think are necessary.
Can anybody help explaining the exception and maybe know where it comes from?

Note that the application code works fine, all necessary dependencies get resolved when I debug the code, e.g. `IOptions<somesetting>` gets resolved just fine. It's just the test that is failing and I don't know where it comes from.

If I filter out all services where name starts with `IOptions` it also fails on `ILogger` with

> System.ArgumentException: Implementation type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger`1[T]' can't be converted to service type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[TCategoryName]'

Again, logging works fine in the application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list of service registrations contains both non-generic (e.g. `HomeController`), closed-generic (e.g. `ILogger<HomeController>`), and open-generic (e.g. `ILogger<T>`) registrations, while `GetService` can only be supplied with non-generic and closed-generic types.

In other words, while iterating the list, you encounter the registration with the `ServiceType` of `ILogger<T>`, but calling `provider.GetService(typeof(ILogger<>))` will fail, because: which `ILogger<T>` do you actually want? Remember, open-generic types like `ILogger<T>` are *templates*, you need to fill in the blanks (i.e. the `T`) at runtime in order for it to become a 'real' type.

I think the root of your issue is the confusing exception message that MS.DI throws. It would have been much nicer it it threw an exception like the following:

> The request for type ILogger<T> is invalid because it is an open-generic type: it is only possible to instantiate instances of closed-generic types. A generic type is closed if all of its type parameters have been substituted with types that are recognized by the compiler.

The above message is an exception that comes directly from another open-source DI Container.

The solution here is to exclude all open-generic registrations while validating your DI registrations. e.g.:

```cs
static void TestServiceResolve(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    foreach (var item in services)
    {
        if (!item.ServiceType.ContainsGenericParameters)
        {
            provider.GetService(item.ServiceType);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that explains it perfectly for me.